# C3P0 connection is not recovered after network outage until server restart

Tags: java, oracle, connection-pooling, c3p0

We have used c3p0 ComboPooledDataSource for connection pooling with Spring JdbcTemplate to access oracle 11g database. after some time (it seems after a short network outage), all request to acquire a connection from the pool will get timeout exception. This will not be solved until our weblogic server is restarted (no need to restart database server).

```
Caused by: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.TimeoutException: A client timed out while waiting to acquire a resource from com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@a261ecc7 -- timeout at awaitAvailable()
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1317)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:557)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:477)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:525)
```

I have checked database current sessions and also c3p0 logs and there is no connection leak (only 50 connections of 1550 are used).
I have also noted that after network outage, there will be no new connection acquired by c3p0 (acquire_increment is increased but managed connections keep going down from 50 to 10).

Our datasource configuration:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="properties" >
            <props>
                <prop key="oracle.net.CONNECT_TIMEOUT">20000</prop>
                <prop key="oracle.jdbc.ReadTimeout">70000</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <!-- Connection properties -->
        <property name="driverClass" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//host:port/db_name"/>
        <property name="user" value="*****"/>
        <property name="password" value="*****"/>
        <!-- Pool properties -->
        <property name="testConnectionOnCheckout" value="true"/>
        <property name="checkoutTimeout" value="30000" />
        <property name="debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces" value="true" /> <!-- Turn this on only for debugging -->
        <property name="preferredTestQuery" value="select 1 from dual"/>
        <property name="initialPoolSize" value="3" />
        <property name="maxAdministrativeTaskTime" value="30" />
        <property name="maxIdleTime" value="600" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="1550" />
        <property name="maxStatements" value="0" /> <!-- Disable statement pooling -->
        <property name="maxStatementsPerConnection" value="0" /> <!-- Disable statement pooling -->
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="5" />
        <property name="numHelperThreads" value="15" />
        <property name="unreturnedConnectionTimeout" value="600" /> <!-- Should set this for debugging leaks -->
    </bean>
```

I have no idea what's really happening.

**Update**
Sorry, edited configuration (Test was wrong in my question but not in my actual config file)

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

1. You may not be getting the Connection testing that you think you are. You set a property called `TestConnectionOnCheckout`, but the property's name is `testConnectionOnCheckout`, with a lower case `t`.
2. You may well have a Connection leak. 50 is an oddly round number of busy Connections for when your application freezes, and a `maxPoolSize` of 1550 is likely meaningless because it is higher than what your back-end supports.
3. You are configured, with `unreturnedConnectionTimeout` and `debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces` to debug Connection leaks, but your `unreturnedConnectionTimeout` is very long. You'll have to wait 10 minutes after things freeze up before you'd observe (in your logs) any check-out stack traces of Connections that eventually leaked. Consider making this smaller while your are debugging, something like 30 secs, so you get reasonably good information about Connection leaks.
4. You set `properties`, `user`, and `password` as distinct values. That might not be so great. Ultimately `user` and `password` get set in the JDBC properties. If `user` and `password` get set before the `properties` property is set, you might end up replacing the properties object with authentication credentials and making requests without a correct user and password. If you are explicitly setting `properties`, consider doing so with something like...

   ```
   <property name="properties" >
       <props>
           <prop key="oracle.net.CONNECT_TIMEOUT">20000</prop>
           <prop key="oracle.jdbc.ReadTimeout">70000</prop>
           <prop key="user">*****</prop>
           <prop key="password">*****</prop>
       </props>
   </property>
   ```

...so you can be sure that `user` and `password` get set.

c3p0 PooledDataSources log their config at INFO on pool initialization. It may be worth looking at that, and verifying that it is the config you expect to see.

Comment: sorry for TestConnectionOnCheckout, it was a mistake in my question. updated the question.